# How much energy is released by an evaporating black hole in the last second of its life?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, black-holes, estimation, hawking-radiation

From what I understand, due to Hawking radiation, black holes lose mass in the form of energy (electromagnetic radiation), with these characteristics:

- The larger the black hole, the less energy it gives off and the slower it evaporates.
- As it loses mass and shrinks, it begins evaporating faster.
- At the end of its life, it approaches infinite evaporation due to its mass approaching zero.
- Thus a black hole dies in a burst of radiation as the last bit of mass inside it explodes into radiative energy.

Given that a Schwarzschild black hole's evaporation rate and lifetime is dependent only on it's mass, all black holes will die identically.

However, I have no idea how fast a black hole actually evaporates.

**How much energy is released in the final second of a black hole's life?** Equivalently, how much does a black hole one second from death weigh?

And how does a black hole's death compare to a nuclear weapon?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The timescale for black hole evaporation by Hawking radiation is

$$t = 5120 \frac{\pi G^2 M^3}{\hbar c^4}$$

Turning this around. If $t=1$ s, then
$$ M = \left(\frac{\hbar c^4}{5120 \pi G^2}\right)^{1/3} = 2.3\times 10^{5}\ kg $$
Thus the energy released is $Mc^2 = 2\times 10^{22}$ J.

This is 5 million megatons of TNT.

NB: All this *is* available on the wikipedia page on [Hawking radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation#A_crude_analytic_estimate).

Comment: I hadn't seen that, it answers my exact question. :S Thanks though!